# Windows Disk Cleanup issues

Tags: windows-xp

After going through the Windows Disc Cleanup process, some applications cannot run due to their deletion of files in temp.

Some applications are:

- Windows Office 2003
- Adobe AIR

How do I fix this problem?

Edit: My system restore was disabled at that time.

Comment: What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Did you run disk cleanup while those applications where running?

Comment: @TomWij For Windows 2003, the error is this: http://www.salesdesktop.net/i/faq-img/q-45.gif
        For Adobe AIR, the error is this: http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6707/screenshot1yh.jpg

@Nifle No

Answer (score 0):

Try system restore or try re-installing the applications, it will surely fix this problem. and from now onwards try to avoid using Windows disk clean up(as it may sometimes currupt the files), you can use Tuneup Utilities http://www.tune-up.com/

Comment: Windows Disk Clean-Up does not corrupt files...

Comment: If full Windows Disk Clean-up not occurs than it may corrupt the file, as it creates file nodes.

Comment: My system restore was disabled >.<